# Spark DataFrame UDF Partitioning Columns

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, user-defined-functions

I want to transform a column. The new column should only contain a partition of the original column. I defined the following udf:

```
def extract (index : Integer) = udf((v: Seq[Double]) => v.grouped(16).toSeq(index))
```

To use it in a loop later with

```
myDF = myDF.withColumn("measurement_"+i,extract(i)($"vector"))
```

The original vector column was created with:

```
var vectors :Seq[Seq[Double]] = myVectors
vectors.toDF("vector")
```

But in the end I get the following error:

```
Failed to execute user defined function(anonfun$user$sparkapp$MyClass$$extract$2$1: (array<double>) => array<double>)
```

Have I defined the udf incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce the error when I try to extract the elements that don't exist, i.e. give an index that is larger than the sequence length:

```
val myDF = Seq(Seq(1.0, 2.0 ,3, 4.0), Seq(4.0,3,2,1)).toDF("vector")
myDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [vector: array<double>]

def extract (index : Integer) = udf((v: Seq[Double]) => v.grouped(2).toSeq(index))
// extract: (index: Integer)org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction

val i = 2

myDF.withColumn("measurement_"+i,extract(i)($"vector")).show
```

Gives this error:

> ```
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$extract$1: (array<double>) => array<double>)
> ```

Most likely you have the same problem while doing `toSeq(index)`, try use **`toSeq.lift(index)`** which returns None if the index is out of bound:

```
def extract (index : Integer) = udf((v: Seq[Double]) => v.grouped(2).toSeq.lift(index))
extract: (index: Integer)org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction
```

*Normal index*:

```
val i = 1    
myDF.withColumn("measurement_"+i,extract(i)($"vector")).show
+--------------------+-------------+
|              vector|measurement_1|
+--------------------+-------------+
|[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]|   [3.0, 4.0]|
|[4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0]|   [2.0, 1.0]|
+--------------------+-------------+
```

*Index out of bound*:

```
val i = 2
myDF.withColumn("measurement_"+i,extract(i)($"vector")).show
+--------------------+-------------+
|              vector|measurement_2|
+--------------------+-------------+
|[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]|         null|
|[4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0]|         null|
+--------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the debugging of this error has cost me a lot of time. +1 for your detailed answer!